# C# waiting task without blocking UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, dll

Let's start with code:

```
private void StartStopService()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => debugService.Iterate());
    StartStopInit(true);

    //task.Wait();
    if (task.IsCompleted)
        StartStopInit(false);
}
```

I am trying to make a program which will execute list of given DLL's from DB one by one without blocking the UI thread in the meantime. Method provided is ran on button click and it is starting a task to iterate over DLL's.

```
public void Iterate()
{
    foreach (var plugin in runningPlugins)
        ExecutePlugin(plugin);
}
```

Execute method just executes DLL's one by one.

I need a solution to run `StartStopInit()` method after all DLL's finished with execution. If I put `task.Wait()` I will block UI...situation as it is now doesn't of course work because if condition gets passed when task starts. If I implement some kind of endless loop to listen for changes, I will again block the UI. How can I solve this one?

Comment: If you don't block UI, have you considered that you may be able to start the operation again while it is already executing? What I mean is that if `StartStopService` is called on a button, have you considered if you need to disable the button while this is happening?

Comment: The normal way now in the async/await world is to mark your method as `async Task` (instead of `void`), and use `await task;` to wait for the task to complete. Please note my previous comment about not blocking UI.

Comment: Well the end idea is to forward cancellation token on button click if the task is still executing

Comment: Have a look at "Threading" - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikhiln/2008/04/12/multi-threaded-web-service-calls-a-c-code-sample/

This will allow you to start a new thread for the processing of your DLL's and keep the separate thread uninterrupted for the UI interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, you should move to the new `async/await` keywords and surrounding support.

For the particular code in your question, here's what I would do:

1. Mark the method as `async Task` to make it clear to calling code that this method is async
2. Use `await` on the task inside the method to halt execution and "wait" for the task to complete before continuing

Specifically, this is what it would look like:

```
private async Task StartStopService()
{
    StartStopInit(true);
    await Task.Run(debugService.Iterate);
    StartStopInit(false);
}
```

Timing-wise I would signal to surrounding code that the method is now executing before spawning sub-tasks.

Also consider adding try/catch blocks, what would happen if the sub-task throws an exception?

```
private async Task StartStopService()
{
    try
    {
        StartStopInit(true);
        await Task.Run(debugService.Iterate);
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        // What to do here???
    }
    finally
    {
        StartStopInit(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great! How can I give it a variable name? `var task = await ...` doesn't work? I would like to forward it a cancellation token

Comment: To forward a cancellation token you must send it as part of the parameters, if the task returns something, ie. it is defined as `Task<T>` where `T` is some type, then you can use `var result = await task` to wait for the task and grab the results, but if it is just `Task`, then you can only wait for it to complete. However, again, a cancellation token must be given to the method as the parameters.

Comment: I know, but in order to do that, I need to register task as variable, to know whether it is running or not? I tried with `var task = new Task(()=>..)` but then if I do `await task` it doesn't start. And `await task.Start()` throws error...EDIT...got it, nvm, thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need to know if it is running or not? `await task` won't continue until the task has completed?

Comment: Because if it is running I am able to click on button "cancel" to send cancellation token forward

Comment: How about: You enable the cancel button when you start the task, you disable the button when the task has completed? Then all the cancel button have to do is cancel the token and disable itself?

Comment: In any case, you can get a variable for the task on the outside, the `StartStopService` method should return a task and you can cancel this one.